# React layout component to render specific routes in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, gatsby, reach-router

I am using Gatsby with `@reach/router`, I have this simple router

```
<>
  <Router basepath="/video">
    <Auth path="/assessment/:keyId" />
  </Router>

  <Layout>
    <Router basepath="/video">
      <PrivateRoute path="/register/:keyId" component={Register} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/tutorial/:keyId" component={Tutorial} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/test/:keyId" component={Test} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/questions/:keyId" component={Questions} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/complete/:keyId" component={Complete} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/personality/:keyId" component={Personality} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/results/:keyId" component={Results} />
    </Router>
  </Layout>
</>
```

And On `Layout` Component I have as simple as this:

```
<>
  <Header />
  {children}
</>
```

The problem is in `<Auth/>` component. It renders with `<Header/>` on it. Why? I'm wrapping a specific routes to render with `<Layout/>`, everything but the `<Auth/>`. What I am doing wrong? Any solutions?

Comment: You have same `basepath` for both the `Router` that render `Auth` and `Layout`.

Comment: @UtsavPatel Yes, for a reason I want to wrap some routes with Layout but not all of them